# Quantidade de números maior que 7 numa lista no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero saber qual a quantidade de números é maior que 7 na lista 'a'.

> Obs: Estou usando fatiamento porque no caso que estou pondo em
>   prática, não sei a quantidade de itens que tem na lista.

```
a=[5, 10, 6, 8]
qmaior= a.count([:-1])>7
```

Quando executado, da erro de sintaxe.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer descobrir quais números são maiores que 7 na lista A, então você precisa filtrar para chegar em números maiores que 7. Ainda estou engatinhando em Python, essa é a forma com for que consegui chegar:

(Notei que havia pedido para contar quantos são maiores que 7, erro de leitura minha, contagem adicionada, caso não queira que apareça quais são maiores, apague o **print(filtro_lista**))

```
a=[5, 10, 6, 8]

qmaior = 7

filtro_lista = [c for c in a if c > qmaior]

print(filtro_lista)

print('Quantidade de números maior que 7:', len(filtro_lista))
```

Answer (score 1):

Só mais uma opção:

```
def maiorq(num=None, lista=None):
    return sum( n > num for n in lista)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    valor = maiorq(num=7, lista=[10,8,2,4,60,3])
    print(valor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) combinada com uma [`Expressão Geradora`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) para se obter a quantidade de itens em uma lista que apresentam valor superior a `7`:

```
a = [5, 10, 6, 8]
print sum( i > 7 for i in a )
```

Saída:

```
2
```